# Formula for creating identity column in Excel

Tags: excel, formulas

I'm sure my terminology is off, I just want a formula to put in a column in excel where each cell equals the cell above it + 1. End result I make the first cell 1 and the rest count up from there. Maybe there's a more correct way to do this. Suggestions?

Comment: SO is for programming-related questions, not general software use questions. For that we have [SuperUser](http://superuser.com). I've voted to move your question there, where it is more suitable. Thanks. :) (And you can  just use `=A1 + 1` in cell `B1`, and then copy the formula down as many rows as you'd like. It will adjust the formula for you automatically as long as you don't use absolute references.)

Comment: I believe he means put **=A1+1** in cell *A2* and copy down.

Answer (score 2):

A more versatile approach (no copying down etc) is Series Fill, on the Ribbon under HOME > Editing - Fill. Seed the start cell with the start value (`1` in the example), if necessary reselect it, and as shown if to increment by `1` down a column one hundred times:

[image: SO10128153 example]

Can be across a row instead, dates etc, but the main advantage over `=A1+1` may be that no formula is involved.

Answer (score 0):

```
=IF(B2<>"",A2+1)
```

This is a way to only populate the number once the rest of the row start being filled out. I had a macro that did this, but teams can't use macros, so I found this formula that sufficed.